# How to fetch record from deep nested association?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, activerecord, rails-activerecord, ruby-on-rails-5

I have these 3 models for example. Board, Truck, Driver.

[Here's a sketch of what I have](https://i.stack.imgur.com/iAM20.jpg)

Truck has many drivers and driver belongs to truck.

Then I have a board, board has collection of trucks.

What I can't seem to figure out is how to get Driver record on the front end through the board and truck.

I have `@boards = Board.all`

But I cannot do this (inside each block) `board.truck.driver.first_name`. How can I get access to the driver who belongs the truck?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are doing it wrong!. As *truck has many drivers*, this won't work `board.truck.driver.first_name` You should do `board.truck.drivers` and loop through it like below

```
<% board.truck.drivers.each do |driver| %>
  <%= driver.first_name %>
<% end %>
```

Comment: I like this approach better, I would need to show all drivers of the truck. thanks.

Answer (score 1):

Based on what you mentioned, the TRUCK has many DRIVERS. Which means that each TRUCK will have an array of DRIVERS. Try doing something like `board.truck.drivers.first.first_name` (assuming you want the first and currently the only driver).

Comment: Yeah! that was it. What I was missing is the understanding that you must call `.first` to actually fetch the record? Thank you for the answer.

Comment: you can also do a `.where()` before the `.first` if you need to select which driver to show based on a database field.

Answer (score -1):

You can also define a through association, so `board.drivers` will become a valid collection

```
Class Board
  has_many :trucks
  has_many :drivers, through: :trucks
```

See [ActiveRecord::Associations](http://api.rubyonrails.org/classes/ActiveRecord/Associations/ClassMethods.html) for details.